# AttributeError: module ' ' has no attribute 'Command'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

In my Django project ,there is a file(module) which is used to load csv data.

```
project/apps/patients/management/commands/load_patient_data.py
```

Inside the file(module):

```
import psycopg2
import csv
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', dbname='patientdb',user='username',password='password',port='')
cur = conn.cursor()

with open(r'apps/patients/management/commands/events.csv') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',' ,quotechar=' ')
        for row in spamreader:
            cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO patients_event (patient_id, event_type_id , event_value ,event_unit, event_time) VALUES
                  ('{row['PATIENT ID']}','{row['EVENT TYPE']}','{row['EVENT VALUE']}',
                   '{row['EVENT UNIT']}','{row['EVENT TIME']}')""")
conn.commit()
```

When I run:

```
 python manage.py load_patient_data
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'apps.patients.management.commands.load_patient_data' has no attribute 'Command'
```

Any friend can help?

Comment: it looks like you are running a simple script as a django command. Have you tried running `python project/apps/patients/management/commands/load_patient_data.py`? If you want to run it as a command you have to follow the command API by django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `load_patient_data.py` file

Write follwing

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        import psycopg2
        import csv
        conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', dbname='patientdb', user='username', password='password', port='')
        cur = conn.cursor()
    
        with open(r'apps/patients/management/commands/events.csv') as csvfile:
            spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar=' ')
            for row in spamreader:
                cur.execute(f"""INSERT INTO patients_event (patient_id, event_type_id , event_value ,event_unit, event_time) VALUES
                          ('{row['PATIENT ID']}','{row['EVENT TYPE']}','{row['EVENT VALUE']}',
                           '{row['EVENT UNIT']}','{row['EVENT TIME']}')""")
        conn.commit()
```

Then simply run  `python manage.py load_patient_data`